# Need a stored procedure to return a particular date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a range of 1st Sep to 31 Oct. Now I need a stored procedure where I can input a particular date and want the procedure to show all ranges till todate.

for exp: if I put 18/7/1999, I must get:

```
1/9/1999 - 31/10/1999
1/9/2000 - 31/10/2000
1/9/2001 - 31/10/2001
.
.
.
1/9/2011 - 31/10/2011
```

Comment: This looks more like you input a particular year and the expected output is the predefined range for all years from the input year until the current year.

Comment: @Neil: August will be skipped as the range is from 1st September to 31st October.

Comment: How are the begin and end dates of the range stored in the table? Are all the ranges stored OR are they stored as only 2 fields like this: 1900-09-01 00:00:00.000 and 1900-10-31 00:00:00.000 OR are they stored as varchars like: 1st Sep and 31st Oct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure below accepts your reference input date, range begin date and range end date. The year part of the range begin date and range end date does not matter. I usually keep them as 1900 while sending them as parameters.

Instead of accepting the range dates as parameters, you can do a select inside the sp to get them from your table where you have them stored.

The output is delimited by a semi-colon and can be changed to any other delimiter by modifying the sp. (or accept it as a parameter). You can then use your code to parse through this.

The construction of the temp dates is purely arithmetic and has no varchar conversions, hence will be faster.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDateRanges 
    @InputDate datetime
    ,@RangeBeginDate datetime
    ,@RangeEndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Year int, @DayOfMonthBeginDate tinyint, @MonthBeginDate tinyint, @DayOfMonthEndDate tinyint, @MonthEndDate tinyint
    DECLARE @tempStartDate datetime, @tempEndDate datetime, @Result as varchar(8000)

    -- Get the first range
    SET @DayOfMonthBeginDate = DATEPART(dd, @RangeBeginDate)
    SET @MonthBeginDate = DATEPART(mm, @RangeBeginDate)
    SET @DayOfMonthEndDate = DATEPART(dd, @RangeEndDate)
    SET @MonthEndDate = DATEPART(mm, @RangeEndDate)
    SET @Year = YEAR(@InputDate)
    SET @tempStartDate = DateAdd(day, @DayOfMonthBeginDate - 1, DateAdd(month, @MonthBeginDate - 1, DateAdd(Year, @Year-1900, 0)))
    SET @tempEndDate = DateAdd(day, @DayOfMonthEndDate - 1, DateAdd(month, @MonthEndDate - 1, DateAdd(Year, @Year-1900, 0)))

    -- Check if the inputdate is greater than the range dates for the first year
    IF(@tempStartDate < @InputDate) 
    BEGIN
        SET @tempStartDate = DateAdd(year, 1,@tempStartDate)
        SET @tempEndDate = DateAdd(year, 1,@tempEndDate)
    END

    -- Loop through each year starting from the year of the input date until the current date
    SET @Result = ''
    WHILE(@tempStartDate < getdate())
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = @Result + Convert(varchar(10), @tempStartDate, 101) + ' - ' + Convert(varchar(10), @tempEndDate, 101) + '; ' + CHAR(13)
        SET @tempStartDate = DateAdd(year, 1,@tempStartDate)
        SET @tempEndDate = DateAdd(year, 1,@tempEndDate)
    END

    SELECT @Result
END
GO
```

Execute the sp as below. Please note that my DB is configured for mm/dd/yyyy. You could use dd/mm/yyyy in the parameters and it should still work as the sp does not hardcode any dates.

```
EXECUTE [GetDateRanges] '7/18/1999','9/1/1900','10/31/1900'
```

The result was:

```
09/01/1999 - 10/31/1999;  09/01/2000 - 10/31/2000;  09/01/2001 - 10/31/2001;  09/01/2002 - 10/31/2002;  09/01/2003 - 10/31/2003;  09/01/2004 - 10/31/2004;  09/01/2005 - 10/31/2005;  09/01/2006 - 10/31/2006;  09/01/2007 - 10/31/2007;  09/01/2008 - 10/31/2008;  09/01/2009 - 10/31/2009;  09/01/2010 - 10/31/2010;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your range all in one field?  (i.e., two dates in a single field?)

In that case:

```
SELECT
   range
FROM
   table
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, right(range,10)) <= @date
```

BTW -- if you're storing your date range in a single field as a string like 'dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy', you won't be able to use an indexed search.  (unless you can find a way to compare that field to your parameter without re-arranging / re-formatting it.).

Or if you have two fields (range_begin, range_end), then...

```
SELECT
   cast(range_begin as varchar(10)) + ' - ' + cast(range_end as varchar(10))
FROM
   table
WHERE range_end <= @date
```

Comment: FYI, if you do the "manipulation" on the column (like in the first code example: `CONVERT(datetime, right(rage,10))`) you will not be able to use an index.  do the manipulation on the @variable and the index can be used.

Comment: @KM -- yeah, I saw that...wasn't sure what other choice there would be though if he's storing his dates like that.

Comment: @KM -- btw -- I'm reading-up on dynamic searches here: http://www.sommarskog.se/ (thanks to @ Martin Smith) -- admittedly, not finished yet, and I'm not sure if it has a solution to this or not.  If you know a 'sargable' way to do the query above, I'd love to see it (not being a smart@$$ -- I really am trying to puzzle it out).

Comment: From the question, I do not think that all ranges are stored in the database. Instead, only the day and month are stored. Probably like 1900-09-01 00:00:00.000 and 1900-10-31 00:00:00.000